# Отрицание в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

С помощью библиотеки `re` требуется выделить весь текст, за исключением тегов. Как выделить теги знаю: `regex = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')`. Знаю, что `^` дает отрицание применительно к символам. Как грамотно сделать отрицание тега в данном случае?

Пример входных данных:

```
<p><strong><em>Читайте также: <a href="https://regnum.ru/news/economy/2527650.html" target="_blank">Набиуллина рассказала, как сделать рубль «привлекательным»</a></em></strong></p>
```

Искомый результат:

`Читайте также: Набиуллина рассказала, как сделать рубль «привлекательным»`

Comment: подменил теги пустотой через `regex.sub('', somexml)`

Comment: Приведите пример текста и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = """<p><strong><em>Читайте также: <a href="https://regnum.ru/news/economy/2527650.html" target="_blank">Набиуллина рассказала, как сделать рубль «привлекательным»</a></em></strong></p>"""

new_text = re.sub('<.+?>', '', text)
print(new_text)
```

Или поиск текста между тегов:

```
# Решение в лоб через перебор разрешенных символов
# new_text = ''.join(re.findall('>([\w«»:\s,]+)<', text))

new_text = ''.join(re.findall('>([^>]+)<', text))
print(new_text)  # Читайте также: Набиуллина рассказала, как сделать рубль «привлекательным»
```

Но я бы лучше через парсер:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print(root.text)
```

Консоль:

```
Читайте также: Набиуллина рассказала, как сделать рубль «привлекательным»
```

Comment: Если позанудствовать, то, может, через `re.sub` делать лучше с шаблоном `<.*?>` ? Чтобы отлавливать "пустые теги". мало ли...

Comment: @strawdog, `<>` такие что ли? :)

Comment: ну да. кто его знает, что попадётся.

Comment: @strawdog, это даже не тег, а просто две треугольных скобки. Теги имеют название и должны закрываться. Думаю, не нужно параноить :)